# Issue with adding marker to folium map inside thread and streamlit

Tags: python, multithreading, streamlit

Using the following code I am trying to add marker to folium map inside thread on webapp using streamlit.

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_folium import folium_static 
import time
import folium
import threading 

m = folium.Map(location = [13.0, 77.0], tiles=None, zoom_start = 5, control_scale = True)
basemap3 = folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap', name='Open Street Map').add_to(m)

img_path_1 = "Path to Img File 1"
img_path_2 = "Path to Img File 2"
folium.Marker(location=[13.0, 77.0], icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image=img_path_1, icon_size=(50, 50))).add_to(m) ## Point 1

def plot_beacon_events():
    ctr = 0
    while True:
        ctr = ctr + 1
        if ctr % 2 == 0:
            folium.Marker(location=[0, 0], icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image=img_path_1, icon_size=(50, 50))).add_to(m) ## Point 2

        else:
            folium.Marker(location=[10, 10], icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image=img_path_2, icon_size=(30, 30))).add_to(m) ## Point 3
                    
        time.sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target = plot_beacon_events, daemon = True, args = ())
st.runtime.scriptrunner.add_script_run_ctx(t)  
t.start()
    
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=True).add_to(m)
folium_static(m, width=1100, height=500)
```

With the above code I am able to add marker to the map (## Point 1), whereas I am unable to add markers to the map inside thread (## Point 2, ## Point 3).

How can I resolve the issue?